# Generating signals at a particular time in Python

Tags: python, linux, signals

I am running my code in Linux os. I want to know if it is possible to generate a signal at a particular time in one function which is caught by another function in Python code?
By signal I mean like SIGALRM

Comment: What do you mean by "signal"? This is very vague; it could be anything from a return value to a [Unix signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal) to a modification of some object's state. If you mean the kind of signal the tag specifies, do you want some other process to receive the signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `SIGALRM` signal (read *carefully* [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) ...) can be emitted by alarms or timers, notably those created by [timer_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) and set by [timer_settime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_settime.2.html) (or the older [setitimer(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setitimer.2.html) ...). You set the [signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal) handler using [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html).

Notice that signals are sent to the process (or to some thread in it), independently of the function currently executed. They could be masked using [sigprocmask(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigprocmask.2.html).

If you want to send or raise a signal, use [kill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html). From outside your process (i.e. in some other terminal), use the [kill(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html) command.

You want to use the Python wrappers of these [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall). Read about the [signal](http://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) module of Python.

And read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) to get a better picture (in your mind) about these issues.

Perhaps the Linux specific [timerfd_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) could be useful to you (at least if you have some [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) around e.g. [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)).